# Catch button clicked in a Qtablewidget cell

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I am adding 2 buttons in each cell of my Qtablewidget and I want to perform a specific action for each clicked button. The problem is that I am only able to detect the click on the entire cell but not which clicked button. I am using pyqt4 and Python 3.5

Could you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are already watching the [`QTableWidget::cellClicked(int row, int column)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellClicked)-signal with some slot, or?
You could try to acquire the sender, which of both buttons it was, by something similar to this:

```
#include <QtCore/QMetaObject>
#include <QtCore/QMetaMethod>

{
    QMetaMethod const metaMethod = sender()->metaObject()->method(senderSignalIndex());
    qDebug() << "invoking caller: name and signature:" << metaMethod.name() << "|" << metaMethod.methodSignature();
}
```

(please adapt yourself to PyQt).

---

Or: you add connections for each of the buttons for each cell at the creation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I used the cellclicked signal to invoke a method in wich i get the current cell clicked